# Google Maps Geolocation API returns the same location

Tags: php, geolocation, google-api, google-geolocation

Every MAC i put into the Google Maps Geolocation API i get the same answer, this is the code i use:

```
<?php
    $mac = "12:34:56:78:90:AB"; //the MAC address you are looking for
    $google_api = "AIzaSyAizb.................."; //my API

    $data = array("macAddress"=> $mac);                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

    $ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=' .     $google_api);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                         
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.turkel.com/1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $result;
?>
```

And the return is always:

> { "location": { "lat": 38.907230999999996, "lng": -77.036464 },
>   "accuracy": 95000.0 }

Comment: is this to do with finding the cell towers from a mobile device?

Comment: i get: -43.532054 172.636225

Comment: Christian, Nope is for finding a router location.
Dagon, can i ask what MAC have you tried? (i want to try too) (and if you put these location through https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?hl=en if you get the right location)

Comment: you cant find a router that way; i used the mac address you supplied above

Comment: So for what is that?
LOL, it's an example MAC (1234566890AB).